# jquery touchstart is not working on android device

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I created a App with cordova , that uses the jquery touchstart event:

```
    $("#jqmbtn").on("touchstart", function (event) {
      alert("touchstart")
      if ($("#Suchfeld").val() != ""){
          startsearch($("#Suchfeld").val());
      }
    })
```

The touchstart event fires at any of the Simulate in Browser options provided by visual Studio 2017 and it also fires at multiple AndroidVirtualDevice(AVD) provided by Android Studio.
But when I run the app on my device the touchstart event doesn t trigger. 
My device has Android 4.2.2 installed and I also tryed the to get a bug report from the Developer Options of my device , but all I got is a 5MB text file where I can t find any usefull information. 
Is there a option I could use to debug the app on my device or does anyone have a Idea what the reason for this could be ? I really don t know what i can do as I don t get any errors when I run on a emulator. 
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I came across something similar a couple of years ago that I think was was related to touch events being lost on objects that had had transform:translate applied to them. The fix for this was to add a dummy touchstart event listener for the whole document:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function () { });
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a glitch with "click" event not working in IOS Devices(Safari Browser).

So, to quick fix that, I used "touchstart" event for that.

I think you have to use "click" instead of "touchstart" to make that thing work on Android.